# Why does the exception thrown in triggered task isn't reported during build?

Tags: sbt

Having the following build definition file and `sbt 0.13.1`:

```
name := "foobar"

val foo = taskKey[Unit]("foo")
val bar = taskKey[Unit]("bar")

foo := { println("foo") }

bar := { println("bar"); throw new Exception("bar exception") }

bar <<= bar triggeredBy foo
```

When I execute the `foo` task the exception thrown by the triggered `bar` task isn't reported:

```
$ sbt foo
Loading /opt/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/s.savulchik/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/project
[info] Set current project to foobar (in build file:/home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/)
foo
bar
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 12, 2014 6:34:52 PM
```

Instead when I directly execute the `bar` task the exception in reported as expected:

```
$ sbt bar            
Loading /opt/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/s.savulchik/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/project/}foobar-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to foobar (in build file:/home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/)
bar
java.lang.Exception: bar exception
    at $df74d6ea1c7cfacc5a14$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(/home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/build.sbt:8)
    at $df74d6ea1c7cfacc5a14$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(/home/s.savulchik/projects/foobar/build.sbt:8)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (*:bar) java.lang.Exception: bar exception
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 12, 2014 6:33:45 PM
```

Any help is greately appreciated! 
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like this must be an sbt bug...

Comment: Yes, this could be an sbt bug.  You should open a ticket and we'll figure out what that UX should be.

Comment: I opened the following ticket https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1187 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jsuereth commented, this is either an intentional behavior or a bug. http://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1187